# Django not showing templates other than base.html

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am having trouble seeing changes made to any template that isn't base.html. I am currently trying to make changes to the homepage, but changes aren't showing in Chrome. I have the cache disabled in Chrome. This was working for me a few days ago, and I haven't made any changes to URLS or VIEWS.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1">
        <title>

        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/navbar.css' %}">
    </head>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/king.png' %}" alt="King's Designs">King's Designs</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link">Hello, {{user.username}}</a>
                        </li>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</button>
                    </ul>
                {% else %}
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="nav-link">Log In</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<body>
<h1>helloooooo</h1>
</body>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: everything is showing blank in every page except base.html. Home, Contact, Login, etc. None of the templates show anything

Comment: How does your base template look like?

Comment: can share your urls and views code as well

Comment: just posted code of my base.html, only took out script and link tags so I could fit the code on the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the body tag from the all the templates except base.html.The files should look like this

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<h1>helloooooo</h1>
{% endblock content %}
```

Your base.html file should look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>Something
        <title>Sometitle</title>
        <!--Any CSS files-->
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
        <!--Any JS files-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to learning Django and this went right over my head for some reason.